# How to dismiss the BiometricPromptDialog after timeout in android?

Tags: android, android-fingerprint-api, android-biometric-prompt

I'm creating an authentication service where the user must use the fingerprint sensor of the smartphone. I saw that android uses the BiometricPrompt APIs, but there's only one problem: I don't know how to set a timeout that dismisses the dialog after a certain amount of time (the dialog is always on utile the user cancels it or uses the fingerprint). Does anyone know how can I do it?

I've tried modifying the executor parameter of the authentication method, but it seems that the executor is not called.

EDIT

I've updated the code using @Subham Naik advice

```
  timeOutHandler = new Handler();
        timeOutHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mBiometricManager.cancelAuthentication();
            }
        } ,4000);
```

But it works only on the first prompt: after the dialog goes off, the second time it stays on.

Comment: Please update the question with what have you done so far. (ie : code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to cancel the authentication

have you tried with

> {biometricPromptObject}.cancelAuthentication()

Comment: Will this dismiss the dialog?

Comment: This doesn't work when device credential is set to BiometricPrompt. https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/biometric/BiometricPrompt.html#cancelAuthentication()